# Making a script work onload or similar rather than on change

Tags: javascript, onchange, onload

I have a simple js script that I have been using to load up text boxes based on the value in which is selected from a drop down.

The problem: It only loads on change, and I am needing it to load when the page is loaded if the value selected on load is not 0. This script is very confusing to me so I am unable to figure out exactly where I need to update.

The Script:

```
function addInput(){
var arr = [
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 1: <input type='text' name='rew1' id='rew1' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_1'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 2: <input type='text' name='rew2' id='rew2' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_2'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 3: <input type='text' name='rew3' id='rew3' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_3'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 4: <input type='text' name='rew4' id='rew4' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_4'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 5: <input type='text' name='rew5' id='rew5' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_5'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 6: <input type='text' name='rew6' id='rew6' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_6'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 7: <input type='text' name='rew7' id='rew7' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_7'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 8: <input type='text' name='rew8' id='rew8' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_8'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 9: <input type='text' name='rew9' id='rew9' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_9'] ?>'></p>",
"<p style='text-align:center;'>Reward 10: <input type='text' name='rew10' id='rew10' value='<?php echo $connt['reward_10'] ?>'></p>",
];
var el = document.getElementById('select');
var div = document.getElementById('rewards');
div.style.display = "block";
while(div.hasChildNodes()) { div.removeChild(div.childNodes[0]); }

if(el.selectedIndex > 0) {
for(var i = 0; i<el.options[el.selectedIndex].value; i++) {
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + arr[i];
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
        window.onload = function(){
            addInput();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

on your  tag

```
<body onload="return addInput()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting true "onload" behavior can be very tricky.  The problem is that while the setting the body tag on load property technically works, it will fire as soon as the body finishes loading.  There can be similar problems with window onload.

Many more complex web pages will not have finished loading all support files, scripts, or AJAX based based components that they need, and so parts of a script triggered from a naive body onload event may fail.

Many JavaScript frameworks provide a method to manage this situation, that does not fire until all of the resources are ready.  I recommend using the one that is implemented in your favorite framework--and I definitely recommend using a framework, as doing cross browser support without a good one is a nightmare!

For example, in Dojo (until quite recently), you would do:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(/* function */)
```

which fires once all page resources are available.